# Embed a browser in a webpage using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, embed, html

I'm working on a project where I need to embed a very simple browser in a webpage using Ruby on Rails. 
For example, if a user is on my website, he/she can click on a link for a different website, it will open it inside a small window in the same original website. 
Same idea of an embedded browser in mobile apps.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) tag

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try it.